# Is there a way to access files for an AWS Fargate container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I am setting up a Node-RED container in Fargate and attempting to change the settings in for it in order to enable HTTPS connection. However, I cannot identify a way to access settings.js. I mounted it to an EFS, but don't know how to directly access the files there either. How should I go about getting to the files for a container?

Comment: I think you have to update your docker image and update your tasks.

Comment: @FranxiHidro Okay. That was what I thought might have to happen. Granted, I am using the official Node-RED image from DockerHub. I think I can find a way to make that work.

Comment: Official image is not the problem, you can update your code, build a new image, push it to ECR. You cannot access EFS directly, need to mount somewhere.

Comment: +1 to use the original image as a `FROM` and build your own image with the tweaks you need. For the records, if you need an easy way to access EFS you can use this: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/simple-file-manager-for-amazon-efs/